# What data did Philae collect?

Tags: probe, rosetta

What did Philae find?

I'm not asking for yet another summary of on-board instruments and a list which were activated. I'm asking for the actual results - either semi-raw data dumps with results of measurements, or some papers where these are presented in 'cooked' form composition, magnetic profile, whatever was discovered.

<sup>in case these are unavailable at time of writing this question, let it sit open, waiting for them, until they are.</sup>

Comment: There's going to be many papers for many years to come on Philae results.  I think that as written, this question is too broad.

Comment: Is this really the best place to go looking for raw scientific data? I think you'd do better contacting the researchers/research community directly.. or simply pinging the website of the team behind the Philae probe on a weekly basis until you see the announcement...?

Comment: The magnetometers were build at IGEP, TU Braunschweig. So if you want to see an example of magnetic field data, you could go to http://www.igep.tu-bs.de/forschung/weltraumphysik/projekte/rosetta/comet_en.html .

Comment: This is too broad. As in, lacks specificity. Most of its science package is functional, so there's going to be a lot to go through in its data stream. I think you already got the only sensible answer for the time being. But if you'd like to create a collection of resources, I'd invite you to do that in our [meta] where we already have similar threads.

Comment: @TildalWave: I believe the collected data, or the research results will be released as a single entity, or at least there will exist a single central entity referencing the rest, which would make the answer complete and not too broad. It's not like I'm asking people to copy-paste several gigabytes of raw data into the answer...

Comment: @SF. Then I suggest you rewrite the part saying _"I'm asking for the actual results - either semi-raw data dumps with results of measurements, or some papers where these are presented in 'cooked' form composition, magnetic profile, whatever was discovered."_ I was not so much concerned about people posting large amounts of data here than that there will be multiple sources for _"What data did Philae collect"_, _"What did Philae find"_, and already mentioned parts of your question. None are actually one and the same thing.

Comment: @TildalWave: Okay, I'll narrow it down. Will something like 'complete data dump' be of acceptable scope?

Answer (score 3):

ESA implements a [proprietary period](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2014/07/16/access-to-rosetta-data/) of 6-12 months for data from Rosetta/Philae. For example, the images released are only from the navigation camera. The high resolution color images won't be released until next year. But they could of course make some exceptions if they want.

Comment: Well then, someone's in for a necromancer badge :)